# Prove this map is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

$(rcos(t),rsin(t))↦((1/r).cos(t),(1/r).sin(t)), 0≤t≤2pi $

first for $0<r<1$, then for $r>1$

My idea is to say $(rcos(t),rsin(t)) = r .(cos(t),sin(t))$ then the cos and sin map with an identity map so of course they're continuous, then r maps to 1/r is continuous since $r $ =/= $ 0$ in both cases. Though I'm not sure if this is allowed.

basically i'm defining a different map $(r, cos(t),sin(t))↦(1/r, cos(t), sin(t))$ and saying it is continuous.

Comment: What definition are you using for continuity? For the last thing you said: If you prove your new map is continuous then the original map is continuous because multiplication is continuous.

Comment: I have yet to prove that r ↦ 1/r, r=/=0 is continuous, and will do so with epsilon/delta. What I'm lacking is justification for the map from R^2 to R^3 being continuous, based on identity mappings

Comment: or is there a much easier way that im ignoring?

Comment: Well what you are doing is a direct sum of two continuous maps (assuming you prove they are). There is nothing non-continuous there, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: It might be easier to do a direct epsilon delta proof of the original map if you get rid of the trig functions. (hint: polar coordinates to cartesian). As long as you can also prove (or are allowed to use a theorem) that the coordinate transformation is continuous and bijective on the annulus.